# Splitting a customer population in 12 samples (= monthly cycles)

Tags: r, split, sample

I need to split a population of 500.000 customers into 12 representative samples, which shall be contacted monthly.

The 12 samples should be representative as within the product and the life cycle class of this product (A,B,C).
**Means: I need stratified proportional samples by product-id AND lifecycle class (could be concatenated)**

And I do not only need one sample, but the whole population divided on 12 samples.

The result should be the origin table added with the stratified cycle-id (1 - 12).

f.e.:

```
cust_id, product, lifecycle, NEW: cycle_id
10000, 4004, A, 3
10000, 2000, B, 6
10001, 3000, B, 12
```

One customer can owe several products, but the combination customer-product is unique.

Each customer-product combination shall be used only once within the 12 cycles (so no putting back)

How can I do this in R?

Sample data row:

```
cust_id, product, lifecycle
10000, 4004, A
10000, 2000, B
10001, 3000, B
10002, 2000, A
10004, 4004, C
...
```

Comment: Write a function to `sample` the rows within each month.  Then Use `ddply` or `by` to apply the function to each monthly grouping.

Comment: How do you ensure that the 12 samples are representative? Do you need to contact repeat customers in the same month for each product? Or different months? Here's a naive first start to cut your sample into 12 random samples, all of which will be roughly equal in size: `cut(sample(nrow(dat)), breaks = 12, labels=FALSE)` where your data is named `dat`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly but functional solution. I apologize for the bizarre, complicated subsetting, but unfortunately by() stores its data in a very strange way.

```
mysamp <- function(dat){
  samp <- runif(length(dat)) #get 12 random numbers
  samp <- ceiling(samp*12) #standardize between 1 and 12
  return(samp)
}
```

That's the function you will use to divide your populations into 12 samples.
Now say 'zz' is your dataset:

```
cust <- c(101, 101, 102, 105, 107)
prod <- c(4004, 2000, 3000, 3000, 4004)
life <- c('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A')
zz <- data.frame(cust, prod, life)
prodlife <- paste0(zz$prod, zz$life)
zz <- data.frame(zz, prodlife)
```

giving you

```
> zz
  cust prod life prodlife
1  101 4004    A    4004A
2  101 2000    B    2000B
3  102 3000    B    3000B
4  105 3000    B    3000B
5  107 4004    A    4004A
```

Then you need to create a column of 0s to put the cycle.id in (I'm calling it 'cyc' in my example). Attach that to the data.frame like you did to add zz$prodlife. Then you can use these statements to sample and assign the sample to the column:

```
cycle <- by(newzz$cust, newzz$prodlife, mysamp)
for(i in 1:length(cycle)){
    for(j in 1: length(cycle[i][[1]])){
        zz$cyc[zz$prodlife == names(cycle)[i]][j] <- cycle[i][[1]][j]
    }
}
```

The by() statement is doing all of the work there, and the horrible for loops are just assigning the sampled values to the correct spots. Because the 'by' class is subsetted inconveniently, I couldn't come up with a more efficient way to do this assignment, but maybe others could...? In any case, this gave me:

```
> zz
  cust prod life prodlife cyc
1  101 4004    A    4004A   6
2  101 2000    B    2000B   5
3  102 3000    B    3000B   7
4  105 3000    B    3000B   8
5  107 4004    A    4004A   1
```

Of course, this example is too small to tell if the samples are stratified correctly, but this should work. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Liz, yes, I need stratified proportional samples not only by the product-ID, but also by the lifecycle (A to C). I could also concatenate both fields to one. Can you explain me your idea with the by() statement? Thanks, Rainer

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comment. Hopefully that clears up what I meant with the by statement-- working on this, I definitely learned what a chore it can be to use by()! Hopefully the loops don't slow this down too much, but I couldn't think of a way around it.